# Why is my HttpWebRequest unable to post data, did I get the code wrong?

Tags: c#

```
string url = "http://localhost/panas/index.php/api/v1/data";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

var postData = "nama=" + txtEmail.Text;
postData += "&status=" + txtFName.Text;
postData += "&keterangan=" + txtLName.Text;
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Do you get an error ? If so - please post the complete and precise error you're getting!

Comment: try to use `try{...} catch(Exception ex){...}` and see what is the exception that you are getting. edit the question and add the exception.